# Changing diagram size to specific size in mm with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an existing Excel file I need to work with. It contains a line graph where measurement results are plotted. All the referencing is done via names. The graph is called "ChartResult".

Obviously Excel discriminates the graph area (the "outer") and the plot area (the "inner") where the graph is plotted. Please correct me if I'm wrong, also learning the preferred english nomenclature would be of great help.

My goal is to print the (page containing the) table so that the division/auxiliary lines have a specific distance from each other. My thinking was that if I define the scale of the axis (the max and min values) and define a size of the graph I would acheive this goal.
However in Excel I can only type in the size of the whole graph area, which is the outer thing, so not helpful when I want to define the size of the graph, the inner thing.

I started using VBA to acheive this but haven't been succesful:

```
Sub Groesse_eingeben()
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ChartResult").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Selection.Left = 0
Selection.Top = 0
Selection.Width = 200
Selection.Height = 200
End Sub
```

This code is changing the size an position of the graph but not to what I expected it to be. Is the input of Selection.XY in pixels or mm? I naively assumed mm but my graph becomes smaller than 200x200 mm, around 60x60 mm.

Thank you!
Chris

System:
Microsoft® Excel® 2016 MSO (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20128)
Win10 Pro 21H2

**Update**:
Ok, the input size is points. But how to specify the exact size of the graph?

[image]

On the screenshot there are two dotted borders: One, the inner, is the actual size of the visible graph the other is the size of the graph object. To cause more confusion: Both are within the graph area, which I called "outer" area above :)
How can I input the exact numbers for the actual visible graph?

Comment: Sizes are specified in points (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.plotarea.height)

Comment: Thank you @Shrotter!
Know the next problem would be that the "inner" area is actually bigger than the visible graph size: If I drag it around a dotted borderline indicates it's real dimensions. Can I somehow find the objects actual width and take that in account when doing the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the outer width of the chart (`ChartObject`) with the `.Width` property, and the inner width of the chart with the `.Chart.PlotArea.Width` property.

Here is a sub that takes a chart and widths as inputs, and updates the chart:

```
Private Sub SetChartWidths(Ch As ChartObject, OuterWidth As Long, InnerWidth As Long)

    ' Set the outer width of the chart
    Ch.Width = OuterWidth
    
    ' Set the inner width (plot area width)
    Ch.Chart.PlotArea.Width = InnerWidth

End Sub
```

**EDIT START**

And here is how you can use the sub:

```
Private Sub UseSubroutine()

    ' Store the chart object in a variable
    Dim LineChart As ChartObject
    Set LineChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
    
    ' Run the sub
    SetChartWidths Ch:=LineChart, OuterWidth:=200, InnerWidth:=150

End Sub
```

If you're having trouble using the `SetChartWidths` sub, and it is in a different Module than the code you're calling it from, you can remove the `Private` from the front to change the [Scope of the sub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility).

**EDIT END**

As for what widths to use, that will be up to you.

Comment: Thank you @TehDrunkSailor.
However the subroutine isn't shown in the makro list. It seems that deleting the content of the frist braces (are they called arguments in the VBA syntax?) and changing it from `Private Sub` to ``Sub`` makes it avaiable. Which isn't quite intended...

Comment: If this sub is in another module, you can remove the `Private` and it will work just the same.  It should now show up in the macro list.  But I don't understand why removing the first argument would change anything.  Can you explain what problems the `Ch` is causing?

Comment: It starts to appear as soon as I remove the arguments. Rewriting `private` removes the sub from the macro list as expected but somehow my system isn't happy with the argument as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  See if it makes things clearer.